# how to get dspace controldesk realtime data by python?

Tags: python, dspace

how to get dspace controldesk realtime data by python? I am writing a python scirpts to get dspace motor realtime data.But I don't know how to get it.

Comment: StackOverflow is a place to ask for suggestions. Its recommended you try something and look for suggestions when you get stuck. Please add what have you tried till now.

Answer (score 0):

The interface to be used is the [XILAPI](https://www.dspace.com/en/inc/home/applicationfields/our_solutions_for/xil_api.cfm). With this you can measure and calibrate data on any by dSPACE supported hardware. But you will not get the data in realtime. To access and evaluate realtime data you must write a [RealTimeTesting](https://www.dspace.com/en/inc/home/products/sw/test_automation_software/automated_test_execution_in_re.cfm) python script.